# Right way of doing an outlined container?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I want to do an outlined container with some text in its upper part. I don't want to use tables if I can avoid them. The container should look like this:

[image]

I can use html5, but only the supported set for IE10. Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Got some code?

Comment: I have one very ugly and verbose, with tables. I'm looking for a better way

Comment: The  [`fieldset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/HTML/Element/fieldset) and [`legend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/legend) element should help you out.

Comment: @elias94xx  Didn't know about them. They are perfect for the job!

Comment: As @cimmanon states, leyend and fieldsets are meant for form grouping. I'm not using forms, so the chosen answer is more html compliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mwv6L/6) should get you started.

Have the container positioned `relative` and the `h1` positioned `absolute`ly so it can overlap.

Comment: As I'm not using forms, and fieldset and legends are for forms. Your answer is definitely the *HTML compliant one*. Thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using two different elements. First Element will contain the Second element that show up as the title on the top. you'll need to set the `position` of the first element to `relative` and the second element to `absolute`. Then use `left`, `top` or `bottom`, `right` to position the inner element. Also make sure the background color of the second element matches the background color of the first element's parent element.

#### [Try out this working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qNwru/)

#### Example Code

```
.main {
    margin-top:20px;
    border: 4px solid #444;
    position:relative;
    padding:10px;
    padding-top:30px
}

.main .title {
    background:white;
    position:absolute;
    top:-25px;
    left:10px;
    padding:5px;
    font-size:26px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Here's something similar using the `fieldset`:

```
<fieldset>

    <legend>Category</legend>    

    <p>CONTENT</p>
    <p>CONTENT</p>
    <p>CONTENT</p>
    <p>CONTENT</p>

</fieldset>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/scUzR/

Comment: Fieldset should only be used for grouping form controls, not because you like the way it looks.  http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/fieldset

Comment: depot's answer recreates the appearance of a fieldset/legend with other elements.